# Synology Server. Bipolar ports and connections are driving me insane

Tags: apache-2.2, synology

I've never worked with a Synology server before so maybe it is something entirely obvious I am missing- but down to the letter, I've set up the Apache Web Server that came pre-installed. Now occasionally when I hit port 80 (curl or through web browser) I get my web pages- every other time I get the Apache 2 Test Page. When this occurs, FTP is unavailable to the server, as is SSH (ports 21,22), DiskStation on port 5000 seems to be offline. Then suddenly it will all come back.

During one of my ssh sessions I got:

```
Connection reset by peer
```

and the server seemed to change its fingerprint

Is there anything I can do to ensure reliability? Is there a cause for these intermittent blackouts?

I can develop the site locally, so I'm not concerned about long ssh sessions, but ideally the web server shouldn't freak out.

Maybe my network outside of Synology is messed up? I don't know, I honestly don't know what to think. If you have any idea what's going on, or can point me to resources that do I'd be grateful.

(This is the right StackExchange for this right?)

Comment: So how are you connecting to the Synology Server? Using the Local IP address (192.168.1.100) or using the public IP? (If using your public IP, have you set up port forwarding correctly)

Comment: Public IP, seems strange that I would be able to access the server at all then?

Comment: If the synology works as it should be when accessed locally (within the LAN) then at least we know the Synology is not the issue. Maybe some connectivity issue from router / firewall in between the incoming connection and the synology.. but I don't know where to start looking .. sorry.

Comment: Thanks though. I'm going to double check everything and get back to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my router configuration was incorrect. The web server should have never have been 'publicly' accessible. That's what threw me. After fixing this, I was able to reliable connect to the server. However, why I was able to connect to the server before the configuration change was made is beyond me. I think it must have been something aside form the Synology server that was allowing my requests to seem as if they were within the network.

This whole project has been from my lab and it would seem that our network is fairly convoluted. Trying to work from home earlier, I was unable to reach certain resources at all. So it would seem that whatever I was connecting to at work had occasional glimpses of the Synology server's network. Why this was periodic and why it happened at all is a bit of a mystery to me. They should have been completely separate. If anyone can provide an explanation or hypothesis, I'd be more than willing to mark your answer as correct over mine.

Comment: Actually. It still doesn't work